# cakephp plugin data validation

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form on my homepage from an element in my Leads plugin.  I have this in my Lead model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'last_name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
        ),
    ),
    'phone' => array(
        'rocket' => array(
            'rule' => array('phone', null, 'us')
        ),
    ),
);
```

My app is validating correctly because it's not posting to my database unless I fill in required fields.  The problem is that the because my url isn't /leads/add it's not showing my custom error messages on my fields when I submit the form.

I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using an element.  Anyone have any ideas or had trouble with this before?

Answer (score 0):

The rule should be notEmpty instead of notempty. What is working right now is the allowEmpty set to false which makes sure the field is not empty using `!empty($field) || is_numeric($field)`.